# What is my spell save DC as a level 1 Assassin archetype rogue? (I have no spells)

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, rogue, assassin

What is my spell save DC?

I am a level 1 Rogue (going Assassin archetype) and have no spells.

My stats are as follows:

- STR: +1
- DEX: +3
- CON: +2
- INT: +1
- WIS: +0
- CHA: +2

Comment: What feature or ability are you trying to use that requires a spell save DC?

Comment: @RyanThompson I don't know, I am new to DnD, and before I join a party I have to fill out a form about my character. It says "Spell Save DC [8 + Spell Casting Modifier + proficiency]" with an input box below.

Comment: @AnAverageGalactophagist Does the form throw up an error if it’s left blank?

Comment: @sevenbrokenbricks It is a google form and a required question, although I was just given an answer by Louis Wasserman

Comment: @AnAverageGalactophagist which is to leave it blank, but if I’m understanding you correctly, the form won’t accept that for an answer.

Comment: @sevenbrokenbricks I just said 'i dont have any spells'

Comment: @RyanThompson I checked that question out, but found that it doesn't quite apply, or at the least I don't see how it does. That question is asking how the item interacts with a rogue, but I have no such item, and any answers would be discussing how things work with that item.

Comment: @RyanThompson The barbarian question is older, is fundamentally the same question, and most importantly, has a good, well-backed-up answer as the accepted answer, while the thief question has a fairly terrible, absolutely not backed up at all, answer accepted.

Answer (score 11):

If you have no spells, you have no spell save DC.  Leave it blank.

Spells and spell saves are associated with a specific spellcasting class and a specific spellcasting ability.  For example, if you are multiclassed as a cleric/wizard, you will have a cleric spell save DC (based on Wisdom) and a wizard spell save DC (based on Intelligence).

The feature that gives you access to spells will tell you your spellcasting ability for those spells, e.g. the Spellcasting class feature for most classes, Pact Magic for warlocks, the Magic Initiate feat, etc.  Your spell save DC is equal to 8 + your proficiency modifier + your spellcasting ability modifier associated with the spell.

Comment: Alright, will do. Thank you for the help, apparently have to wait 9 minutes b4 marking this as the answer to my question.

Comment: @AnAverageGalactophagist it’s considered good etiquette on stack exchange sites to wait 24 hours in case someone else posts a better answer

Comment: @DaleM ok i wait

Answer (score 0):

### 10

If the formula for calculation a spell save DC is 8 + spell casting modifier + proficiency, then the formula would spit out 8 + 0 + 2 = 10. (0 comes from not having a spellcasting ability)

Though it should (and seemingly has been in [Louis Wasserman's](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/52922/louis-wasserman) [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/156144/what-is-my-spell-save-dc-as-a-level-1-assassin-archetype-rogue-i-have-no-spell/156146#156146)) identified that this stat is pretty much irrelevant for your character as he or she is currently; if they had a spellcasting ability it would be stated in the class abilities.

If you absolutely need to put something in the box, then it seems for now 10 is a technically correct number to put there.

Comment: I think your math is wrong.

Comment: What makes you think Wisdom is the spellcasting ability here?

Comment: @inthemanual Thanks for the catch :). and question has been edited, the 0 doesn't come from wisdom, but rather from the character not having a spellcasting ability.

Comment: Assassin rogues don't have spellcasting so they do not have a spellcasting stat. All the classes that have a spellcasting stat have that stat stated in the rules for that class.

Comment: Good point, added to the answer.

Comment: '--' doesn't have a modifier of 0, I don't think.  That part of this answer could use more support, if it is correct.